# Qual expressão regular utilizar para dar replace em todas as ocorrências encontradas em um arquivo no Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, regex, gwt

Bom, eu tenho um arquivo CSS de mais de mil linhas, onde para cada classe lá listada, existe um código `@external` declarando a mesma, exemplo:

```
@external agora-eu-posso-usar-minha-classe;
.agora-eu-posso-usar-minha-classe{
    /* CSS... */
}
```

O fato é que eu descobri que se eu der um `@external *` no inicio do código, ele já assimila todas as classes CSS e eu não preciso declarar uma por uma.

Pois bem, com o problema resolvido, agora meu código ficou cheio de `@external [...]` e eu gostaria de dar um replace em todas essas linhas com Expressão Regular.

**Qual a expressão que retornaria tudo dentro de `@external [...] ;`?**

Pontos a se considerar:

- O `[...]` pode conter qualquer nome de classe CSS válido;
- O `[...]` pode conter várias classes declaradas, ex: `@external classe-1, classe-2;`

O que eu estou tentando (não, não tenho nenhum conhecimento em regex) é mais ou menos isso:

```
($@external+\w+\(\))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como é a sintaxe do eclipse, mas uma regex que pode resolver esse problema é a seguinte (testado com javascript): `^@external (.+)$`

Essa expressão casa tudo que está entre parênteses (grupo) até o final das linhas iniciadas em @external, sendo possível dar um replace e usar o conteúdo do grupo.

[Veja aqui](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/?pattern=%5E%40external%20(.%2B)%24) uma explicação visual de como essa regex é interpretada.